# Django viewset error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: python, django, model, serialization

I'm trying to create a ViewSet for the Course model (to simply display all courses), but I'm getting the following error when trying to access it. I'm new to creating ViewSets and Django in general, what am I doing wrong?

Django 2.2

**Error**

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `title` on serializer `CourseSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'.
```

**CourseViewSet**

```
class CourseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Course.objects.all()
        serializer = CourseSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**CourseSerializer**

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'active',
            'individual_result',
            'course_duration',
            'video',
            'manager_id'
        )
```

**models/Course**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    individual_result = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    course_duration = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  
    video = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  
    manager_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should serialize with **`many=True`**, since a queryset is a *collection* of objects that can contain zero, one, or more elements:

```
serializer = CourseSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

For more information, see the [*Dealing with multiple objects* section <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects).

Comment: Ah okay this works, thank you! Sorry for going off-topic but do you maybe also know how to pass something to the request parameter?

Comment: @SJ19: what do you mean with "pass something to the request parameter"?